# Optional values for functions (not methods)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know there is a way to get optional values or default values with methods in objective c, but is there a way to do this with functions?

Attempting the same way as you would a method gives a conflicting types error.

ie..

```
void myfunc();
void myfunc(NSInteger myval);
```

Comment: Question not specific to xcode, iPhone nor iPad. (retag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Cocoa there is nothing called functions.

If you are taking about default arguments as in C++, there is nothing such in Cocoa.

However you can have multiple method sharing same name with different arguments as :

```
 init //no arguments
 initWithName: //one argument
 initWithName:age:  //two arguments
```

You can reach near to this C++ default argument method as :

```
int sum(int a, int b=0, int c=0){
    return a+b+c;
}
```

In objective-c, but never do this:

<strike>-(NSInteger)sumA:(NSInteger)a withB:(NSInteger)b withC:(NSInteger)c{</strike>

```
    if(c==NIL) c=0;
    if(b==NIL) b=0;
    return a+b+c;
}
```

And call it as : `[self sumA:10 withB:5 withC:nil];`

Comment: You can define a function in a class as I have done in my OP.  Then simply call it with `myfunc();` in your code as long as the .h is included.

Comment: I see, so a value must still be passed.  So it can't be optional then.

Comment: There certainly are functions in ObjC and Cocoa. `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` is the entry point for every Cocoa program, just like a C program. Passing `nil` for an integer argument is incorrect -- that's an object-typed variable. It works, because its value is the same as integer 0, but it shouldn't be used as some kind of sentinel value for POD types.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: I just gave an example for that so we can reach near to that, however there is no such advantage for that, I didn't mean to use that :(